# Freeze DataGrid columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I need to  freeze the first columns in a ASP.NET Datagrid web control.

I've got approximately 20 columns. I'm using visual studio 2008.

It should be like Excel. Also need to freeze header as well.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
<asp:GridView ID="grdview_items" runat="server"
DataSourceID="SDS_items" 
EnableViewState="false" Width="800">
<HeaderStyle  CssClass="grdview_headers"  />
 <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-Width="200px"  HeaderText="Item1"><ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="300px" ItemStyle-Width="300px"   HeaderText="Item2"><ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="300px" ItemStyle-Width="300px"    HeaderText="Item3"><ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
<style>
.container 
{
    overflow:auto;
    margin-left:10px;
    height:300px; 
    width:710px;
 }

.grdview_headers
{
    color:#330000; 
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:790px;
    margin-top:-1px;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.container tr>td:nth-child(2)').css("background-color", "#EAEAEA").css("position", "absolute");
    });
</script>
```